# Sending a file with Play using zipoutputstream

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka, akka-stream

I am providing a download feature for a file that may exist on my disk. This is in play/scala. I have the following download method that gives me the file. But I want to use `ZipOutputstream` and send the file. I do not want to zip the file first on disk and then do it. I am not sure how to achieve it. Also, in that case what will the length parameter be like?

```
def downloadLocalBackup() = Action  {
    var pathOfFile = "/opt/mycompany/backups/mydir/backup"
    val file = new java.io.File(pathOfFile)
    val path: java.nio.file.Path = file.toPath
    val source: Source[ByteString, _] = FileIO.fromPath(path)

    Ok.sendEntity(HttpEntity.Streamed(source,None, Some("file"))).withHeaders("Content-Disposition"->s"attachment; filename=backup")
}
```

Editing my post and adding the code that I wrote, but I am not happy that I have to read the zip file into the zip stream. I think that is not optimized?

```
 def downloadLocalBackup2() = Action {
    var pathOfFile = "/opt/mycompany/backups/backupdir/backup"
    val file = new java.io.File(pathOfFile)
    val path: java.nio.file.Path = file.toPath


val enumerator = Enumerator.outputStream { os =>
  val zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(os)
  zipStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("backup2"))
  val is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(pathOfFile))
  val buf = new Array[Byte](1024)
  var len = is.read(buf)
  while (len >= 0) {
    zipStream.write(buf, 0 ,len)
    len = is.read(buf)
  }
  is.close
  zipStream.close()
}

val kk = Ok.sendEntity(HttpEntity.Streamed(Source.fromPublisher(Streams.enumeratorToPublisher(enumerator)).map(x=>{val kk = Writeable.wByteArray.transform(x);kk}),
  None, Some("application/zip"))
).withHeaders("Content-Disposition" -> s"attachment; filename=backupfile.zip")
kk
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use GZIPOutputStream in this case:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream

val txt = "text to zip"
val arrOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
val zipOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(arrOutputStream)
zipOutputStream.write(txt.getBytes)
zipOutputStream.close()

val result: Array[Byte] = arrOutputStream.toByteArray
```

Comment: I have few questions on above as I do not fully get it. I have to ask that when you say ``zipOutputStream.write...`` are you not reading the whole text? Can it be avoided? And I have an existing file on the disk that I want to add to the zip stream. The above example is slightly different I suppose?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ZipOutputStream`, you could use [`Compression`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/scaladsl/Compression$.html) to gzip-compress a stream of `ByteString`:

```
val source: Source[ByteString, _] =
  FileIO.fromPath(path)
        .via(Compression.gzip)
```

You would need a consumer that could handle the stream of compressed data using the corresponding `Compression.gunzip()`.

As for the `contentLength`, explicitly provide it instead of using `None` (if you keep it as `None`, Play will load the entire file into memory to compute the length):

```
val contentLength = Some(file.length)

Ok.sendEntity(HttpEntity.Streamed(source, contentLength, Some("file"))).withHeaders("Content-Disposition" -> s"attachment; filename=backup")
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I am not clear on two items. I may know the length of the existing file that is not compressed. But how can I know the length of zipped file beforehand? Because if I do "file.length", it may not be the right length. Isn't it? Also, ``Compression.gunzip`` as you suggest will work with normal browsers or not?

Comment: hey @chunjef, can you tell me how do I know the contentLength if I am doing a zip? I am running out of memory if I use zipoutputsream for large files as I do not know the length